# Is it possible to fabricate decent food from various types of junk and dirt?

Tags: food

Let's say we have fabricating machine which disassembles anything on molecular level and assembles again in different order. We know that food consists of proteins, fat, carbohydrates and vitamins.

Assuming that we don't have any problem with energy source: can we fabricate any type of food from various types of junk (metal, plastic and paper) and even from dirt?

Comment: We already have such devices; they're called "plants".

Comment: ...and also "chickens".

Comment: @ Marvin the Paranoid Android: They work really well on solar power, too, and you really don't even need the junk, unless maybe you want to build cultivators & other tools out of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> We know that food consists of proteins, fat, carbohydrates and vitamins

To a lower level, that boils down to carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, nitrogen, sulfur, calcium, potassium, phosphorus and other elements.

> Can we fabricate any type of food from various types of junk (metal, plastic and paper) and even from dirt?

If you take a bar of iron, you will get just iron and maybe some oxygen if it was a tad rusted. In general with metals alone you will miss most of the elements I listed above.

If you take only plastic, you will get carbon, hydrogen and maybe nitrogen or oxygen, but other elements will be missing.

A tad better goes with paper: being made of cellulose fibers, it allows you to get carbon, oxygen, hydrogen.

Therefore if you want to make food for heterothroph beings, you are better off starting from organic wastes, since they bring a more complete set of the needed elements.

Atoms have no memory of where they were before, so the food that you will make in this way, if is has the same composition, will be indistinguishable from the "true" one.

To put it in another way, when farmers use manure to fertilize the ground where they grow trees and crops, the plants will use the atoms contained in the manure to make the apple or the wheat which will end up in the apple pie you are eating right now.

Comment: Dirt is probably the best bet of the list we’ve been given, since it’ll contain organic debris.

Comment: So if I just throw all types of junks and dirt into one pile. Disasseble then, and then assemble it into pizza. It will be just exact type of pizza that are being sold in shops?

Comment: @Mr.D, yes. Atoms have no memory of their history.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Well this make term "junk food" in literal sense :)

Comment: One should note that the more different the input and output, the more energy this transformation will likely require. Even with handwavium providing unlimited energy, the waste heat will be a serious problem.

Comment: Don't forget, C, H, O and N are all just hanging around in large quantities in the air.

Comment: Also, note that that's where plants get them from, not from the manure and dirt! Otherwise trees would be sitting in holes in the ground. They get nitrogen, phosphorus, sulphur and trace elements from the ground, as well as H and O from water, but the rest is from the air. (Unless they're legumes, in which case they get N from the air as well.)

Comment: @Nathaniel: Your legumes don't get the N from the air all by themselves, though.  They've made friends with nitrogen-fixing bacteria.

Comment: @jamesqf that's correct. I should also slightly correct what I said above: I believe that in photosynthesis, plants get most of their O from CO2 in the air and not from H2O. They get their H from the H2O and the O ends up as oxygen in the air.